Make new form "Main Form" - how?
I have a program with two forms - a "login" form, and the main application form.
Now, the Login form is displayed first (after all, if you don't log in, the program shouldn't continue to the second form). Once login credentials are accepted, I do a ShowModal on the second form, then - when the second form closes - exits the program.
This is all fine and dandy, but - if the user minimizes the second form, it doesn't go to the task bar, but instead minimizes to a small title bar at the bottom of the screen, just above the task bar.
How can I make Windows understand that this second form is the "main" form and that it should behave as a main form should, and minimize to the task bar?

The MainForm is established by the 1st call to Application.CreateForm() at runtime. DO NOT create your Login Form with CreateForm

I would suggest a different approach that encapsulates all necessary code in the login form unit and leaves the dpr as is.
Assuming the login form is named TLoginForm.

Don't auto-create TLoginForm, but keep it in the dpr uses clause.

Make TLoginForm return mrOK in ModalResult only when login is successful.

Add a class method named Execute to TLoginForm with this content:
class procedure TLoginForm.Execute;
begin
  var instance := Self.Create(nil);
  try
    if instance.ShowModal <> mrOk then 
    begin
      Application.ShowMainForm := False;
      Application.Terminate;
    end;
  finally
    instance.Free;
  end;
end;


Add the following code to the end of the login form unit:
var
  SaveInitProc: Pointer = nil;

procedure InitApplication;
begin
  if SaveInitProc <> nil then TProcedure(SaveInitProc);
  TLoginForm.Execute;
end;

initialization
  SaveInitProc := InitProc;
  InitProc := @InitApplication;
end.



This will call the login form inside the Application.Initialize call of the dpr. If the login fails Application.ShowMainForm := False will prohibit the main form to be shown and the Application.Terminate will end the loop in Application.Run.
The advantages of this approach are mainly that it is independent of the main form and that it doesn't interfere with the IDE maintaining the dpr file.

The MainForm is established by the 1st call to Application.CreateForm() at runtime. DO NOT create your Login Form with CreateForm, if you are currently doing so.
And, DO NOT use ShowModal to show the MainForm. Let Application.Run show it normally.
Your Login Form should be shown modally before Application.Run is called. If login fails, exit the app immediately.
